# Почему fetchone() возвращает None?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlite3

Столкнулся с проблемой получения данных из БД.

```
def addKid():
    PARENT = input("NAME of father or mother: ")
    KGARTEN = input("NAME of KinderGarten: ")

    cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO Parents(NAME) VALUES(?);", PARENT )
    con.commit()

    cur.execute(f"SELECT max(ID_PARENTS) FROM Parents WHERE NAME = ?", [PARENT])
    PARENT_ID = cur.fetchone()
    con.commit()
    print("PARENT ", PARENT_ID)

    cur.execute(f"SELECT ID_KDG FROM kinderGarten WHERE NAME = ?", [KGARTEN])
    KGARTEN_ID = cur.fetchone()
    con.commit()
    print("KGARTEN_ID ", KGARTEN_ID)
```

Проблема заключается в том, что при вызове `fetchone()`, возвращается `None`.

Пытался найти в чем причина, нашел ответ насчет `con.commit()`,  но это тоже не помогает. Есть какие-то идеи?

Иногда функция отрабатываать правильно и возвращает 2 значения `PARENT_ID`, `KGARTEN_ID`, а иногда частично и возвращает `PARENT_ID`, `KGARTEN_ID = None`.

Comment: Немного странно, что в первом `cur.execute` у вас значение `PARENT` передаётся без скобок, а дальше в таких же конструкциях такое же значение обёрнуто в скобки (т.е. из него сделан список). Не в этом ли дело?

Comment: А вот в запросах строковые переменные наверное нужно брать в кавычки. Т.е. не просто `?` использовать, а `\"?\"` или `'?'`. Попробуйте

Comment: @CrazyElf
Попробовал, вылетает ошибка
    cur.execute(f"SELECT max(ID_PARENTS) FROM Parents WHERE NAME = '?'", PARENT)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 7 supplied.

Comment: Хм, интересно. Ну значит я не прав про скобки. Попробуйте просто с кавычками тогда

Comment: замените `cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO Parents(NAME) VALUES(?);", PARENT )` на `cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO Parents(NAME) VALUES(?)", [PARENT])`

Comment: @MaxU это не влияет на проблему

Comment: @alcoccoque, вы попробовали? Я вообще не понимаю как у вас отрабатывает INSERT с параметром в виде скаляра - он ожидает кортеж или список и должен был ругаться в этом месте...

Comment: @MaxU в конструкции с VALUES(?) не ругаеться, то есть без разницы как передавать PARENTS, а вот там где WHERE NAME = ?, там надо прописывать [PARENTS]

Comment: @alcoccoque, а вы проверяли что при этом вставляется в Parents.name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

я бы делал это так:

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect(r"/tmp/test.sqlite")
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute("create table parents(id integer primary key autoincrement, name text)")

def add_kid(con, parent):
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO Parents(NAME) VALUES(?)", [parent])
    con.commit()
    # return last generated AUTOINCREMENT ID
    return cur.lastrowid

def get_kgarten_id(kgarten):
    cur.execute(f"SELECT ID_KDG FROM kinderGarten WHERE NAME = ?", [kgarten])
    kgarten_id = cur.fetchone()
    return kgarten_id[0] if kgarten_id else None

PARENT = input("NAME of father or mother: ")
KGARTEN = input("NAME of KinderGarten: ")


parent_id = add_kid(con, PARENT)
kgarten_id = get_kgarten_id(KGARTEN)
```

Comment: Cпасибо за совет,а для чего в add_kid прописывать cur = con.cursor(), таким образом создаем новый курсор? Если просто передать в функцию con, это не  сработает?

Comment: @alcoccoque, можно конечно передавать в функцию и `con` и `cur`, но это дело вкуса...

Answer (score 2):

Убери con.commit, это пуш в БД, а ты тянешь от туда.

Мой вариант кода :

```
sql = "SELECT id_user FROM users WHERE id_user=%s"
        val = (str(item),)
        cur.execute(sql, val)
        chek = cur.fetchone()
```

Comment: Убрал con.commit() ,но это все равно не помогает, возвращает None, но бывает иногда и нормальный результат

Answer (score 1):

```
   db = 'database.db' 

   def search(a):
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
        cursor = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM table WHERE a = ?", (a,)).fetchone()
    
        if cursor is None:
            conn.close()
            return None
        else:
            conn.close()
            return cursor[0]
```